# Putting two seaborn distribution and boxplot side by side in Python

Tags: python, seaborn

I would like to create two different Seaborn plots: a distribution plot and a boxplot, appearing side by side. This is the code I have:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(3)
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
# Making age variable        
age = [7,5,8,5,1,2,5,8,5,5,5,2,6,8,8,2,3,8,25,3,82,8,2,6,29,3,1,5,10]
    
# create the figures
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
        
# boxplot
sns.boxplot(y = age, ax= ax[0]) 
  
# distribution plot        
sns.displot(age, kind = 'kde',color = 'red', 
                alpha = .1, fill = 'true',ax = ax[1])

# show plot
plt.show()
```

The code generates the following output:
[image: Output from above code]

**Desired solution.**
I would like to have the Distribution plot inside the second square. This code works if both plots are the same (e.g., both histograms for example). But I would like a distribution and a boxplot side by side. Is that possible? I really appreciate all the helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because you're using `displot`. If you run your code, you get a warning:
`UserWarning: displot is a figure-level function and does not accept the ax= parameter. You may wish to try kdeplot. warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)`

You just need to replace your code from `displot` to `kdeplot`, something like the following:

```
sns.kdeplot(age, color = 'red', 
                alpha = .1, fill = 'true',ax = ax[1])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: if you use `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(12, 6))` it will give more space between boxplot and kdeplot